# How do I average historical statistics from a dataset with sports results?

Tags: python, dataframe, statistics, dataset

I have tennis dataset and this is the head:

[image: dataset]

Now I want to average FS_1 for a given ID1. In other words, I want to get all players average first serve percentage from the data in this dataset. And all players occur several times.

I know I can do this to get the average value of a field;

```
def mean(arr):
  return sum(arr) / len(arr)

mean(dataset['FS_1'])
```

but how do I get a specific players average?

Comment: You repeatedly refer to a "dataset", but what is the format of that dataset? Is it in a pandas dataframe?

Comment: Yes sorry. It's a xlsx file, read in a pandas dataframe.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Forgot to tag you, but do you know how it's done, or do you know of any resource that explains how it may be done?

Comment: No, I know very little about pandas.

Comment: Can you share your XLXS file and the code to retrieve dataset from XLSX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) method should do the trick:

```
df.groupby(['ID1']).mean()['FS_1']
```